# Laravel Query to select list entry in JSON field

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm storing dynamic data in a MySQL JSON field using Laravel v6.11.0, [nova](https://nova.laravel.com) v2.9.3 and [nova-flexible-content](https://github.com/whitecube/nova-flexible-content) v0.1.13. The data stored looks similar to this:

```
[
  {
    "layout": "source",
    "key": "5ce8e0a877487fe5",
    "attributes": {
      "value": "342",
      "unit": "USD",
      "language": "en",
      "url": "http:\\/\\/google.com",
      "authority": "google.com",
      "entry_date": "2020-01-21",
      "date": "2019-12-21"
    }
  },
  {
    "layout": "source",
    "key": "a82393ce016e8c14",
    "attributes": {
      "value": "444",
      "unit": "USD",
      "language": "en",
      "entry_date": "2020-01-21",
      "url": "https:\\/\\/google.com",
      "authority": "TEST",
      "date": "2020-01-20"
    }
  }
]
```

I was wondering if it's possible to build a Laravel Query to select the second entry based on the `authority` entry? Criteria are:

- `url` should contain `google.com` AND
- `authority` shouldn't be `google.com`

I've found https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#json-where-clauses, but am struggling to put the right query together. Maybe someone could give me some pointers on how to do it? Thank you

Comment: Are you storing the whole array or 1 object per time ?

Comment: The complete JSON is in one MySQL column - that's how the component automatically stores it.

Comment: Ok what about the db column type ? is it text or json ?

Comment: It's a JSON column

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to this [discussion](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/making-a-laravel-54-query-on-a-json-field-containing-a-json-array?page=1) on Laracast

```
$data = App\YourModel::whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(body->"$[*].attributes.url", "\"https://google.com\"")')
        ->orWhereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(body->"$[*].id", "\"http://google.com\"")')
        ->whereRaw('not JSON_CONTAINS(body->"$[*].attributes.authority", "\"google.com\"")')
        ->get();

foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $bodyArr = json_decode($row->body);

    foreach ($bodyArr as $item) {

       if ((preg_match("/(http:\/\/www\.|https?:\/\/google.com)/i",$item->attributes->url)) && (strpos($item->attributes->authority, 'google.com') === false))  {
          dump($item);
          // YOUR CODE GOES HERE
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it, tested on my case

```
YourModel::query()
                ->whereJsonContains('your_json_column', [['attributes' => ['url' => 'google.com']]])
                ->whereJsonDoesntContain('your_json_column', [['attributes' => ['authority' => 'google.com']]])
                ->exists();
```

Hope it will helped you

Comment: This should do the job

Answer (score 0):

You can work on JSON fields like this

```
Model::query()
    ->where('attributes->url', 'like', '%google.com%')
    ->where('attributes->authority', '!=', 'google.com')
    ->get();
```